# Parse, Action on Save (On Device)

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, save

I am building an iOS app using Parse. When any data is saved, of any kind, I want to be able to perform an action. Specifically on a generic save, not after a specific save action as it would be mean doing this at every save through my app.

Is it possible?

i.e.

1. Parse ANY save event triggered.
2. Perform action after save complete.

Answer (score 0):

Some purists consider this a bit of a hack, but this is a problem can can be resolved with method Swizzling. Essentially, you replace a method of a class with your own method. In this case, you would replace the Parse save methods to enable them to send an event as well as perform their original function.

I have a working example of method Swizzling on [Github](https://github.com/picciano/iSwizzle)

This example code augments UIViewController and adds logging functionality to the viewWillAppear: viewDidAppear: viewWillDisappear: and viewDidDisappear methods. But you can use this whereever you need to inject functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here, you can either use Cloud Code and write a `afterSave` hook that will be fired on each save. This would run on Parse servers and you can move fast in terms of logic changes as no client update is required to change the logic behind it. However, these functions are limited to run for 3 seconds tops so you need to be very quick and should not perform any massive operations here. Check the [Cloud Code documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/guide#cloud-code) for details.

The other way, if you really want to do it on the device, fire an `NSNotification` after each save operation, create a class that listens for this notification and performs whatever action is needed after the save. Here as well, check the Apple documentation on [NSNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotification_Class/).

Answer (score -1):

try creating a category on PFObject and creating an custom save

```
- (void) customSave {
   [self save]
   //custom function
}
```

You would need to do this for each and every PFObject save command you intend to use

Comment: Not sure how this actually resolves the problem. Please can you provide more detail

Comment: instead of calling `[object save]` everywhere in you project, you would call `[object customSave]`.  Not really sure if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I don't understand all you have done is made it so instead of calling `[object save]` everywhere they are just calling `[object customSave]` everywhere instead how is that any better? Please explain your answer.

Comment: Can't you subclass save `-(void) customSave { [super save];  /* your special save */ }` instead?